# Get name of file that is including a PHP script

Tags: php, filenames

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

#### index.php

```
<ul><?php include("list.php") ?></ul>
```

#### list.php

```
<?php
    if (PAGE_NAME is index.php) {
        //Do something
    }
    else {
        //Do something
    }
?>
```

How can I get the name of the file that is including the list.php script (PAGE_NAME)? I have tried `basename(__FILE__)`, but that gives me `list.php`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There may be a workaround for your situation.

Comment: I have two types of files, index.php, and the rest of the files are articles. The articles are in articles/year/month/day/name.php each use list.php to get a list of articles which are displayed in a bar, the problem is the location of the script that connects to my database further from the article pages. So I am doing the conditional to see if I need to include(../inc/conn.php) or include(../../../../../inc/conn.php)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];` returns what you want

Answer (score 7):

If you **really** need to know what file the current one has been included from - this is the solution:

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();

$from_index = false;
if (isset($trace[0])) {
    $file = basename($trace[0]['file']);

    if ($file == 'index.php') {
        $from_index = true;
    }
}

if ($from_index) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Or, just the file, `debug_backtrace()[0]['file']`

Comment: Brilliant shorthand, @SolomonUcko!

Answer (score 7):

In case someone got here from search engine, the accepted answer will work only if the script is in server root directory, as PHP_SELF is filename with path relative to the server root. So the universal solution is

```
basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
```

Also keep in mind, that this returns the top script, for example if you have a script and include a file, and then in included file include another file and try this, you will get the name of the first script, not the second.

Comment: Thanks for explaining behavior in the case of nested includes!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can do something like the following:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $page_name = 'index';
        include("list.php")
    ?>
</ul>
```

#### list.php

```
<?php
    if ($pagename == 'index') {
        //Do something
    }
    else {
        //Do something
    }
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Firstly you made a mistake with $page_name and $pagename. Then list.php won't be able to see $page_name assuming you used $page_name in both scripts

Answer (score 2):

In the code including `list.php`, before you include, you can set a variable called `$this_page` and then `list.php` can see the test for the value of `$this_page` and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` works but I recommend to put a `strtolower(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))` to check 'Index.php' or 'index.php' mistakes.

But if you want an alternative you can do:
`<?php if (strtolower(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '.php')) === 'index'): ?>`.