# Get path of parent file from included file in php, I don't need the folder path but the full path of including page

Tags: php, php-include

I have a php file that could be included in different places. I need to have some rule on what to show depending on the including file.

Using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is returning the path of the page itself not the parent file that's including it.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/139874/1252947)?

Comment: You could let the included file expect a specific variable to be defined, that will be set/defined in each including context, before the actual inclusion.
This would also add more semantic value, instead of relying on a specific file path for different behaviour.

Comment: @Pedro Pinheiro, This won't do, because it gives the directory path. All pages involved share the same directory.

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6804550/1252947)?

Comment: @Carsten, I was hoping to centralize the logic of switching specific functionality on and off inside the included page itself, rather that worrying about adding that logic in every place where I need to add the include.

Comment: It sounds to me like an awkward design choice. As your often-used included code has to know what other files are using it (dependency in both directions)... But then again, the second comment from @PedroPinheiro should do the trick.

Comment: Pedro's solutions is not for my problem. You might be right regarding not relying only on the path from your point of view, but I just think this would makes it easier to maintain the code knowing it's only in one place. But I guess your suggestion is the only way around.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

The full list can be found on the [PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: This would give the same result as $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']